# How to set Python multiprocessing pickle protocol for 3.x to 2.x IPC

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

I am trying to establish really basic string-message IPC (no need for objects or anything fancy like that) between two Python processes on the same machine, the listener in Py2 and the client in Py3. This doesn't work out of the box because Py3 MP defaults to Pickle protocol 3, which doesn't exist for the Py2 listener, so the listener crashes on an unrecognized pickle protocol. I wish MP wouldn't pickle at all, I'm just sending strings over the wire and don't see why I should be forced to go through a Pickling step if I choose not to, but if I can't turn pickling off entirely, then how to I tell the client in Py3 to use pickle protocol 0 (or 1 or 2)? I have looked for a solution to this seemingly straightforward question and cannot find an answer, much to my astonishment.

Thank you.

Comment: You certainly can’t just “send[] strings over the wire”—you have to have counts or delimiters (and escaping of some kind) to distinguish messages.  `pickle` is just one such protocol that handles some other types too.  How are you using `multiprocessing` to start such a mixed set of processes?

Comment: I've done lots of message coding. Raw strings work just fine if we handle message management at the application level. Multiprocessing doesn't necessarily have to Pickle for us. The option to send raw byte streams or strings, and to binarize, uuencode, serialize, marshall, and parse messages at the application level is an entirely reasonable approach.

And if not, then the follow up question still stands: how to specify multiprocessing's Pickle protocol for Py2 compatibility.

Don't worry about it at this point. I switched to zmq, which works flawlessly, so no need for multiprocessing.

Comment: For the benefit of others who find this question: I still don’t know how you started a Python 2 process from a Python 3 process via `multiprocessing`.  It’s mostly meant for running multiple copies of the *same* script with the same interpreter, although there is `set_executable` as well as `Manager` and the `connection` module.

Comment: I didn't start one process from another. I'm running two processes, one is a Python 2 script and the other is a Python 3 Jupyter notebook kernel (but could just as easily be a Python 3 script for the sake of argument). I'm just trying to pass messages back and forth between the two. That's all. zmq works fine.